# why the link click event of rich text box not fire in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, hyperlink

I haven richtextbox and I want use hyperlink on it so when user clicked the website link or local file is open. but the event not fired.

1. I checked the event handler from the property windows and is set correctly.
2. I checked the DetectUrls property and is true.
3. I set the debug point on entire line of the link click event, But the program does not enter the event body after clicking on the hyperlink.

my code is:

```
private void TextBoxDefinition_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LinkText.StartsWith("file://"))
    {
        string filePath = e.LinkText.Substring(7);
        Process.Start(filePath);
    }
    else
    {
        Process.Start(e.LinkText);
    }
}
```

why the event not run. how can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The event is only activated when the form's focus is on your RichTextBox, try setting the focus to it

```
private void TextBoxDefinition_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        TextBoxDefinition.Focus(); // Define Focus to RichTextBox
    }
```

Comment: i do not think so. I try with and without your code and the result is same. but now I try something else too. when i create hyper link as i said that event not firing. but when i enter and go on next line the event run. also when I using the rtf format to create the hyperlink the link for website is work fine (after enter and going to next line). but the hyperlink of file not working and save incorrectly (for example for C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\16.txe the e.linktext return c:16txt)

Comment: some minutes ago I find this format for creating the hyperlink. but this format is only create hyperlink for website and not in the utf8.     TextBoxDefinition.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " +      @"{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK """ + url + @""" }{\fldrslt " +    text +@"}}}";

Comment: Try creating a LinkLabel and adding it to the richtextbox then setting the linkclick event to linklabellinkclick. can be a solution too.

Comment: I try both and now the event is worked, but now  I found a strange problem that I can't understand. When the hyperlink is created, the event does not work to firing and open the file. The user must enter to go to a new line. Then type at least about the same length of the above line. After this, by clicking on the hyperlink, the event will be executed and the file will be opened.

Comment: Can you provide a path on github?

Comment: I double check in my project and the internet. I think I find my answer. I create to new project with (.net framework 4.5 and 4.8 (my main project with this) ) and test create hyper link and link click event. in 4.5 everything worked perfectly but in 4.8 i think has bug and have the problem I descript above. so I should rewrite most of my  project as some of tools and library only have 4.8 support

Comment: let me update my qustion.